# how to enable ExplicitExpansion globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, mapper, projectto

I'm using ProjectTo in AutoMapper and I want to set ExplicitExpansion globally, is there any way to customize it instead of this way?
`public class UserDetailResponseProfile : Profile {     public UserDetailResponseProfile()     {         CreateMap<User, UserDetailResponse>()             .ForAllMembers(x => x.ExplicitExpansion());     } }`

I want the ExplicitExpansion option to be the default behavior and use memberToExpand to get the data
`await repositoryWrapper.Users             .ProjectTo<UserDetailResponse>(x => x.Name, x => x.FullName, x => x.Role)             .ToListAsync()`
Data:

`{   "Name": "aaa",   "FullName": "bbb",   "PhoneNumber": "213123213",   "Role": {     "Name": "Insert"   },   "Orders": [     {       "OrderId": 1,       "ItemId": 2     }   ] }`

---> Result:

`{   "Name": "aaa",   "FullName": "bbb",   "Role": {     "Name": "Insert"   } }`

Comment: You can combine it with `ForAllMaps` or use `ForAllPropertyMaps` instead.